# Function arguments and interactive

Tags: interactive, arguments

I am having difficulty seeing how to properly use function arguments with the interactive command.

Suppose I have a function with three arguments `myfunc (arg1 &optional arg2 arg3)`, the last two being optional.  In what circumstances does one need the interactive part to fill the values for `arg1`, `arg2` and `arg3`?

In the case of the prefix argument, does one need to include the prefix argument as a function argument?

It looks to me that besides make a function into interactive command, the interactive expression provides a mechanism for passing arguments to the function when called interactively.

```
(defun change-theme (theme)
  (interactive "a Theme Name: ")
  ...)

(defun history (&optional prefix)
  (interactive "P"))
```

But then one can use things like `completing-read` and `read-from-minibuffer` that can be saved to a variable.  This gives the same utility as `interactive` does for the user to enter some input.

```
(defun cursor-setting ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ( (cseq '("bar" "hbar" "hollow" "box"))
          (csel  (completing-read "Cursor: " cseq nil t "box")) ))
```

But then I can also do

```
(interactive
 (let ((string (read-string "Foo: " nil 'my-history)))
   (list (region-beginning) (region-end) string)))
```

where `read-string` is called inside the interactive command.

One can also use a list as here

```
(interactive
 (list 
    (read-string "Remote host: ")
    (read-string "Remote filename: ")))
```

I am finding the interactive command as one of the most complicated to use.

The following is an important example.  I would think that although the example works, the implementation is quite bad.  Because whilst one can use it interactively, it is not advisable to use it in a non-interactive way because of the call to `read-from-minibuffer`, even though the function would still work.

I wonder whether it is a requirement for all interactive functions to always allow a non-interactive call.

```
(defun workbench (&optional prefix)
  "Make new temporary buffer manually using user input."

  (interactive "P")

  (cond

   ;; -------------------------------------------------
   ((equal current-prefix-arg nil)   ; no C-u

    (message "no C-u")
    (setq thote 1))

   ;; -------------------------------------------------
   ((equal current-prefix-arg '(4))  ; C-u

    (message "no C-u")
    (arktika-automated-workbench))

   ;; -------------------------------------------------
   ((equal current-prefix-arg 1)     ; C-u 1

    (message "C-u 1")
    (let* ( (name (read-from-minibuffer " Name: ")) )
      (arktika-automated-workbench name))))
```

Comment: Which part is confusing, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: It is not really important what I have tried.  What is important is to know some general rules to follow.  Will put some detail.

Comment: For instance, suppose I use the prefix argument `(interactive "P")`, would I need to provide an function argument for the prefix?  What would be the difference whether the argument is optional or not?

Comment: I have provided an answer to your related other question [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/72430/26163). I think that answer mostly answers this question also. But it will probably help to note again that you should consider that interactive function (i.e. commands) can also be called non-interactively. So think about what would be the behavior in that case. Considering this option combined with the info in the other answer, I guess you should be able to figure out what is the best way to go. So just try writing your functions and with time/experience you will find the best way.

Comment: "It is not really important what I have tried" -- You are expected to show what you know so far, and your efforts to date.  You have asked a *lot* of questions in recent times, so at this point it is only reasonable for you to have made some efforts to solve your problems, and to show what you have tried.  Please refer to https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and make sure you are providing the information you know so far.

Comment: Fair enough.  I know quite a few things to which I have elaborated.  But the more I know, the more I can find ways to do the same thing.  So the question is really about understanding some general rules others have learned in terms of design that would make the code straight-forward rather than long-winded.  My latest approach has boon to make a wrapper function for the interactive version of a function has many advantages, rather than writing a function that does everything (interactively and not-interactively).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using current prefix argument value](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/72425/using-current-prefix-argument-value)

Answer (score 2):

In your case, the `interactive` form only needs to pass one argument.

For example:

```lisp
(defun my-func-one (arg1 &optional arg2 arg3)
  (interactive "P")
  (message "%s %s %s" arg1 arg2 arg3))
```

In the `my-func-one` case, the `interactive` form only fills in the `arg1` argument. Argument `arg2` and `arg3` will be set to `nil`. For example, calling <kbd>C-u M-x my-func-one RET</kbd> yields `(4) nil nil`.

```lisp
(defun my-func-three (arg1 &optional arg2 arg3)
  (interactive "P\nd\nm")
  (message "%s %s %s" arg1 arg2 arg3))
```

For `my-func-three`, the `interactive` clause pass three arguments, `P` pass the raw universal argument value, `d` is the value of the point and `m` the mark. <kbd>C-u M-x my-func-three RET</kbd> could yield `(4) 1630 1440`.

Some side comments:

- You use `interactive` to make a function into a command. However, you can still call it as a function.
- If you want to read arguments regardless if you call it as a command or as a function, you could read the arguments in the body of the function. However, in most cases, you would like to design the function so that it gets its input via its arguments. In this case, the `interactive` clause is only used to read the arguments when the called as a command.
- You can use the code form of `interactive` when the string form isn's powerful enough. For example, `(interactive "d\nm")` is equivalent to `(interactive (list (point) (mark)))`. However, in the code form you can use code anyway you want, e.g. read values using auto completion the string form can't handle.

Comment: You have mentioned something I have been struggling with.  The fact that one can read arguments in the body of the function rather than inside an interactive expression.  I have found that there are endless ways of handling user input.  Because even if the function is called non-interactively, one can still call interactive functions that accept user input from the minibuffer.

Comment: True, but as I said, the common way it to make the function only read arguments when called as a command not as a function. However, Emacs lisp allows you do implement this any way you want.

Comment: This would mean that calling `read-from-minibuffer` in the body could make sense.  For instance, I made a function that uses the value of `current-prefix-arg` to determine what user-defined variables get asked in the minibuffer.

Comment: One way to find out what makes sense is to read the code that emacs distributes (you can read the code of external packages as well, but there might be less quality control). E.g looking at Org mode which is a fairly substantial package, there are ten calls to `read-from-minibuffer` in about 130K lines of code. On average, 1 call per 13000 lines of code: not very common. You should also read the functions that do use `read-from-minibuffer` and figure out why they needed to do so. That will improve your understanding far more than any number of repetitive, siimple-minded tests that you cook up.

Comment: To summarize: learn to read code in order to write better code.

Comment: Yes, but I have seen the following declaration `(defun my-message (&optional arg)
  (interactive "P")` where arg is optional and interactive takes the Raw Prefix Argument "P".  This implementation seems to contradict the assertion that there is no way to optionally pass an argument via interactive.

Comment: This makes it possible to call `my-message` as a function without arguments, i.e. `(my-message)`. When used as a command, an argument is always passed. This is normal pattern in Emacs Lisp.

Comment: What happens when I do `M-x my-message`.  It would still be an interactive call, but without arguments.  Was under the impression that interactive would only accept non-optional args.  Yet when I do `C-u 2 M-x my-message` the value of `2` gets read to `arg`.

Comment: When you do `M-x my-message` your function will be called with one argument, that argument represent the universal argument (the numeric prefix). If you don't press `C-u` at all, the argument will be `nil`. If you press `C-u C-u` it will be `(16)`. If you press `C-u 2` it will be 2. etc. The possible values are the same as `current-prefix-arg`.